# JQuery hover img swap, mouse out

Tags: jquery, html

I need help with my jQuery script, the `img` change when mouse hover and the `.conceptcontent` class is displayed, when the mouse leave the `img` is changed back but can I hide the `.conceptcontent` class?

```
(function ($) {
    $(".img-swap").hover(

        function () {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_off", "_on");
            $(".conceptcontent").show("slow");
        },

        function () {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on", "_off");

        });

    var imgSwap = []; $(".img-swap").each(function () {
        imgUrl = this.src.replace("_off", "_on");
        imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
    });

    $(imgSwap).preload();
})(jQuery);
```

html

```
 <title>Untitled Document</title>

 </head>
 <body>
<!--background-->
<div id="intro">
<h1 id="rubrik">Josef Carlsson</h1>
</div>


<div class="meny">
<div id="home"><img src="iconer/home_off.svg" class="img-swap"></div> 
<div id="about"><img src="iconer/ommig_off.svg" class="img-swap"></div> 
<div id="design"><img src="iconer/design_off.svg" class="img-swap"></div> 
<div id="internet"><img src="iconer/internet_off.svg" class="img-swap"></div>
<div id="camera"><img src="iconer/kamera_off.svg" class="img-swap"></div>
<div id="concept"><img src="iconer/koncept_off.svg" class="img-swap"></div> 
 </div>

 <div class="menytext">
<div id="hometext">Start</div>
<div id="abouttext">About me</div>
<div id="designtext">Design</div>
<div id="internettext">Webb</div>
<div id="cameratext">Pictures</div>
<div id="concepttext">Concepts</div> 
 </div>

 <ul class="conceptcontent">
<li>emotion</li>
<li>[in]sight</li>
<li>will i make it</li>
<li>trace</li>
    <li>datemate</li>
    <li>pacman</li>
</ul>
```

this is the html that's used

Comment: Can you show us the html?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just need a hide like you have show()?

EDIT: I'm starting to guess that the animations are queuing up. I tried replicating try this:

```
(function($){
$(".img-swap").hover(
function(){this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
        $(".conceptcontent").stop(true.true).show("slow");},

function(){this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
           $(".conceptcontent").stop(true,true).hide("slow");

 });
```

jQuery stop() stops the current animation.

Comment: i have tried that but then the script repeat it self, and on mouse over the .conceptcontent class is hiden and then shown repeatly don't know why

Answer (score 0):

you can just use this to hide it

```
 $(".conceptcontent").hide('slow');
```

Comment: yes i have tried that but then the script repeat it self, and on mouse over the .conceptcontent class is hiden and then shown repeatly

Comment: maybe you could try hooking up not the hover event, but .mouseenter(function() {...}); and .mouseleave(function() {...});

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of what you've done for mouseover would be:

```
...
$(".img-swap").hover(
  function(){
    this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
    $(".conceptcontent").show("slow");
  },
  function(){
    this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
    $(".conceptcontent").hide("slow");
  }
);
...
```

**Edit:**
I typed slower than the others... I guess fixing your formatting took a minute or two ;)

Comment: yes i have tried that but then the script repeat it self, and on mouse over the .conceptcontent class is hiden and then shown repeatly

Comment: It might be re-firing the event because the image is being swapped? Try assigning the hover event handler to a parent element (e.g. the container div) and see if that helps. Assigning a fixed size to that parent wouldn't hurt either (prevents the div from momentarily shrinking to zero and firing a mouseout before the new image is loaded).

Comment: Show us the html, so we can see where in the DOM the divs and imgs are in relation to each other.

Comment: isn't the parent called? both the .img-swap and -conceptcontent is in a divs,

Comment: Can you just post some of the actual html?

Comment: Try attaching the hover event to "div.meny > div" instead of to ".img-swap" and see if that helps. If not fix the div sizes and try again. (You'll need to refactor the functions too, since $this will be the div not the img)

Comment: i tried with mouseenter() insteed of hover but can't get that to work

Comment: is the problem that it repeats itself (lots of times) or just that when you move from one image to the next it hides-and-then-shows the .conceptcontent? In other words, if you remove "slow" from the show() and hide() calls does it work ok (just showing the conceptcontent when the mouse is over the menu)?